# Where to find the reference for the double dollar PHP syntax?

Tags: php, syntax

i hope that everyone here know the php 'variable variable' syntax:

```
$color = 'red';
$red = 'yes, im red';
echo $$color;
//output: 'yes, im red';
```

but my problem is: how this syntax is named?
i'm trying to find the reference on php.net, with no results (i wanna know if this feature will be kept in php6, the others attributes, etc...)

Comment: "php variable variable" in Google, 1st result. Come on, man. Just kidding. Kind of. :)

Comment: lol i just wrote 'variable variable' on php.net, without see that the default choice is 'function list' and this case, is not a function :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Variable Variables](http://is.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

And yes it will be kept in PHP6 as far as I know.

Comment: Ooo, 10 seconds faster. you can have it. ;)

Comment: <3 You win sometimes though :)

Comment: What keyword did u use to find that page?

Comment: In the search box on PHP.net, select "all php.net sites" in the drop down.

Answer (score 5):

Just to share some tips.

To avoid confusion, you may use the curly braces.

```
${$color}
```

One of my team member removed the double $, thinking of typo error. 
Perhaps doing so will avoid confusion.

Comment: The mantra: "if it aint broke don't fix it" unfortunately does not apply to programmers ;-).

Comment: +1 Nice tip. When reading code that I wrote months ago and see a double-dollar I sometimes get a little confused. Seconds later I realize what it´s meaning :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing this from php would be a really pointless decision as this functionality comes really handy in many scenarios while having no real disadvantages / problems associated with it.